# Becoming a proxy so people can access a website they wouldn't usually be able to

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to build a proxy for users that are in a country where the real domain's blocked. Similar to http://pirateproxy.se/ how would one go about doing that? I'd need images to load ect. Thanks.

Comment: It could be useful to say on which platform do you want to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Run Apache on a domain that they can get to, and configure it to do reverse proxy.  If you search for "apache reverse proxy" you will find several tutorials and references.  To allow images to load, it is best to map a subdomain (rather than a path) to the blocked domain.